# RC4 password recovery

Tags: encryption, brute-force-attack

suppose the password used in the RC4 encryption of a plaintext is an English word of 6 letters that we do not know or forget it . Is it possible to recover it if we only know the ciphertext but not the keystream ? If yes how exactly ? Moreover , is there some software that can do the job ?

Comment: Hint: the answer revolves primarily around what's known about the plaintext, which is entirely unstated. How the password is changed to RC4 key matters too, and is not precisely stated.

Comment: the plaintext is  a message that makes sense   in English language . What do you mean by how the password is changed to RC4 key ?

Comment: In any sound encryption system accepting a password as the key, there is a [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) step (e.g. PBKDF2, Bcrypt, Scrypt, Argon2, Balloon..) transforming the password into key. That slows brute force password search. Without such step, automatically testing all passwords that are an "_English word of 6 letters_", obtaining the corresponding plaintext, and checking if it could be _"a message that makes sense in English language"_ is relatively easy (for large enough message) and requires feasible work.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply . You are totally right . The problem is that I do not know what is the keystream . If I reformulate what you wrote me . Could it be that if I do not know the keystream then it is impossible to recover the password?

Comment: No, the exact opposite! With no key stretching, and enough ciphertext (moderately so), knowing that the plaintext is redundant is enough to find the right password, because the password space is too small and enumerable at low cost.

Comment: you wrote : "knowing that the plaintext is redundant is enough to find the right password, because the password space is too small and enumerable at low cost" Could you please tell me how is it possible to recover the password if we know that the  plaintext is redundant and in English language? I mean could you describe the method that can be used to recover this English password from an RC4 ciphertext which is derived from an enough redundant English plaintext ? Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The general method to recover a short key given ciphertext and knowledge that the plaintext has some discernible characteristic (like: is English text) is brute force. That is

- for each possible key $K$ (much preferably: from most to least likely, at least approximately)

  - decipher ciphertext with key $k$, yielding tentative plaintext $M$
  - test if $M$ has the discernible characteristic, and in the affirmative

    - display $K$ and $M$

This will display the right key; and, for practical ciphers including RC4, long-enough ciphertext and selective-enough characteristic, manageably few or no other. $M$ will help de terming the right $K$ manually.

[This source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/6-letter-words.htm) gives a list of 87151 6-letter words for Scrabble, while [that one](http://wordfinder.yourdictionary.com/letter-words/6) gives 15727, less than $2^{14}$. Make it $2^{17}$ adding common first names and slang, and $k=2^{17+6}=2^{23}$ (still less than 10 millions) with all capitalization of 6 letters; that's a modest number of keys to try.

We need a test with a residual odds of false positive of at most few times  $1/k$. If we have at least 20 bytes of ciphertext, the simplest suitable test is to check if the high-order bit of each $M$ is zero. That can be improved for slightly less ciphertext with better characterization of English text (like: containing a high proportion of vowels).

That's extremely doable: given that RC4 was fast on CPUs of the 1980's, I'm confident it is possible to be under $2^{20}$ CPU cycles per key tested, thus an affordable $2^2$-core CPU at $2^{31}$Hz will crunch all $2^{23}$ keys in $2^{20-2-31+23}=2^9=1024$ seconds, that is a small fraction of an hour. The main assumption is that the 6-letter word is directly the RC4 key, without [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching); and secondarily that not too many of the first output bytes of RC4 are skipped before use.

If the encryption program use competent [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) (as it should) parametrized for $2^1$ second on a machine comparable to the above, performance becomes an issue: we are now talking $2^{1+23}=2^{24}$ seconds, that is over 6 months. We need patience, energy/money, trying passwords from most to least likely, optimizing the code of the key stretching (the rest of the computation has negligible cost), or/and bring more or/and better hardware.

---

Lesson learned: **when using a password to generate a key, competent and generously parametrized [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) is critical**. A long complex password can help on the security standpoint, if it is handled securely; however long complex passwords are often mishandled (written on postit notes hidden under the keyboard, or in a file hidden in an obscure subdirectory) compromising security; or/and lost: the glue or that postit won't stick after a few uses; a hard disk, OS crash /update, cryptoransomware, or plain human error FUBARs the master file, compromising availability.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply . As you wrote that the general method to recover a short key given a ciphertext and a knowledge that the plaintext has some discernible characteristic (like: is English text) is brute force . If the encryption program use a competent key stretching , do you know a good software that can  brute force this password or key ?  I really looked in the internet for days but i could not find a good one except for Cryptool  which is very slow  . Plus  cryptool bruteforces  the plaintext but i need to recover the password so I need  a software that bruteforces the password

Comment: @silver: Brute force password cracking tools are highly specialized with respect to exactly what they attack (that remains vague). In particular, they need to know the _exact_ details of the ciphertext format and stretching, and what they can expect for the plaintext (at least if short). Chances that something ready made exists for a proper (thus stretching) encryption program written independently are practically zero. Chances that something freely or commercially available works to break free or commercial product named xxxx and is not found by googling _password cracking xxxx_ are low.

Comment: I am a newbie in programming that is why I cannot write my own code . So If the chances to find this rc4 password cracking tool are very low even by using google . So how do you think i can bruteforce this rc4  english password? what do you suggest me to do in order to find this password?

Comment: @silver: I recommend that you learn coding. It is to computer what driving is to car: if you can't, you'll need to convince someone who can to perform it for you.  Whoever finds this RC4 password will first need to determine _exactly_ how the password and plaintext are combined into ciphertext: _"RC4 encryption"_ is not precise enough. If there is no stretching and the plaintext is English with more than about 20 characters in the usual ASCII character set, the rest is easy, and in fact a gentle introduction to programming.